# Android is there a way to see what the actionBarItemBackground drawable XML is?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I can set the background of a button to `?attr/actionBarItemBackground` to get ripple effect on a button. Is there a way for me to see what the actual XML for this drawable is within the OS?

My question is about `?attr/actionBarItemBackground` but I would like to know this in general too - for any system drawable - how to see the actual XML?